# Find the limit of $\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{1}{e^n}$

Tags: limits

I want to find the following limit:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{1}{e^n}$$

L'Hopital's Rule looks like it would be a major pain. I was thinking you could change the first term to $e^n$, but that is clearly illegal. According to WA, the answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Take $\tt log'{}s$ first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using series:

$$\log\left[{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\frac1{e^n}}\right]=n^2\log\left(1+\frac1n\right)-n\stackrel{\text{Taylor series}}=$$

$$=n^2\left(\frac1n-\frac1{2n^2}+\mathcal O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)-n=-\frac12+\mathcal O\left(\frac1n\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\frac12$$

So...

Answer (score 0):

$$
n^2\log \frac {n+1}n -n
=n^2\left(\log \left[1+\frac {1}n\right] -\frac 1 n\right)
\sim n^2\left(-\frac {(1/n)^2}2\right) = -\frac 12
$$then using the continuity of $\exp$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{1}{e^n}
=\exp\left(-\frac 12\right).$$